Back porting ffmpeg.dll from electron for windows xp by disassembling
I've recently gotten into a really interesting project of having a fully functional (and as futuristic as possible) physical retro gaming machine with windows xp. I had found One Core Api that successfully works to allow for some programs to work that otherwise wouldn't have. One of them is electron (5.0.13). Thanks to a vast testing between a VM with the kernel extender and a vanilla XP, I found out that the only thing stopping me from succeeding is because it's dependent on an EXTREMELY specific version/fork of ffmpeg (Chromium fork of ffmpeg 4.1) . Due to that being a relatively old fork/version, the build tools/links for some of the stuff are nonexistent right now, so even if I do have the fork locally with all the instructions, I can't build it. (and if I do I have to patch Win Vista+ Api functions, with one custom stub dll I have)
AcquireSRWLockExclusive InitializeConditionVariable SleepConditionVariableSRW InitOnceBeginInitialize InitOnceComplete InitializeSRWLock ReleaseSRWLockExclusive WakeAllConditionVariable WakeConditionVariable
Since I can't custom build ffmpeg I have to patch it's calls by redirecting them to my custom dll that includes these back ported functions and more.
I tried many different ways => IDA Pro, Ghidra, objconv, currently am the closest with "DLL to C"
Ida Pro and Ghidra seem to not be creating assembly code that I'd be able to assemble back after patching.
objconv produces a really accurate disassembly, but the issue is it doesn't have an assembler. And the produced .asm won't assemble with Fasm, masm or nasm
As for DLL to C-> successfully created a quite presentable VS project, the project successfully compiles with only one warning, the byte sizes is quite similar, the problem is => the functions are getting wrongly directed (towards wrong functions in my dll- and thus the ones needed are undefined) And this is too deep to be able to tell if it's a VS version issue, wrong code implementation or if just DLL to C has wrongly disassembled the logic.
Question is, is my last option remaining to manually edit the HEXES of the Import Address Table and Import Names so they get redirected? (the problem is my knowledge in Assembly isn't too good, so I'm not sure if that's all I'd have to do, and even if so, I have a feeling I'd mess up the Virtual Addresses or something.
